# Correct term for a person working two jobs secretly

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm trying to establish what it would be called when a person works two or more jobs in secret.  What is the word for what the person is doing?

EG: John's main employer found out that he is ______ for other companies on his off-time.  He is now in serious trouble.

Comment: If my answer suits your needs, you might consider accepting it...

Answer (score 161):

The correct term for this is ***[moonlighting](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/moonlight)***, which means:

> Have a second job in addition to one’s regular employment.

It often carries a connotation of secrecy. The second job is done under metaphorical moonlight. [Cambridge](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/moonlighting) captures this connotation:

> paid work that you do in addition to your normal job, *especially without telling your employer*.

It fits perfectly into your example context:

> "John's employer found out that he is moonlighting for other companies. Now he's in serious trouble."

---

Here is the etymology according to [Etymonline.com](http://www.etymonline.com/):

> ***[moonlight](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=moonlight)*** (v.)
>
> "hold a second job, especially at night," 1957 (implied in *moonlighting*), from *moonlighter* (1954), from the notion of working by the light of the moon; see ***[moonlight](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=moonlight&allowed_in_frame=0)*** (n.). Related: *Moonlighting*. Earlier the word had been used to mean "commit crimes at night" (1882).

Comment: Though not all companies have a problem with you moonlighting - especially if you're using your own equipment.

Comment: A lot of big companies don't like moonlighting, as the person may same the work for XXX then do a bad job.

Comment: @WayneWerner: Especially if you're moonlighting as a musician when your day job is (say) as an auto mechanic.

Comment: This is also where the term "Moonshine" comes from (referring to liquor made illegally, usually at night by the light of the moon).

Comment: "under metaphorical moonlight" This also implies "under the cover of darkness."

Comment: There is a neocolonialism daylighting, for when someone doing second job at same time as main one ... http://edition.cnn.com/2008/LIVING/worklife/09/24/lw.working.on.the.job/index.html?iref=24hours

Answer (score 6):

I think the moonlighting answer is correct, but in the interest of throwing another word into the mix: you could say that the person is [**freelancing**](https://www.google.com/webhp?ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#safe=off&q=define:+freelance):

> working for different companies at different times rather than being
>   permanently employed by one company.
>
> *"a freelance journalist"*
>
> **synonyms:** self-employed, independent, contract

"John's main employer found out that he is **freelancing** for other companies during his off-time. He is now in serious trouble."

Comment: No, 'freelancing' says nothing about having a main job as well, whereas 'moonlighting' explicitly does.

Comment: @smci Like I said in my post, I agree that *moonlighting* is correct. But *freelancing* could also fit the sentence, depending on the context. Figured I'd throw it into the mix.

Comment: Freelancing is too specific. Freelancers are hired out for individual projects; they don't have a set schedule and salary/wage like an employee. The original question didn't reference the details of the second job, and a freelancer might not necessarily have a "main" job.

Comment: It might not fit the question exactly, but it does fit the asker's example exactly.

Comment: @taimu The word "freelancing" might fit into the example but since it doesn't fit the question - which explicitly targets secrecy - it's not an appropriate answer.

Comment: @VinceO'Sullivan Answers aren't meant to only help the OP. They're also meant to help people with similar, but not exactly the same, questions in the future. I specifically said that the *moonlighting* answer is probably correct in this specific case, but *freelancing* might help with similar questions in the future. The OP even said that both terms are helpful. The mouse-over text for the upvote arrow is "this answer is useful". That was my logic for providing this answer, and I don't think it's "inappropriate" at all.

Comment: My first thought was "moonlighting" but this one got my upvote because I perceive it as more contemporary.

Comment: Freelancing fits in the example sentence and has the right meaning because of context (the existence of a main employer who wasn’t happy about it), but in general freelancing can be done as a main job, not necessarily as a second job (and a second job may not necessarily be freelancing, either). Thus, this is not a good answer to the question.

Comment: @KRyan Like I've said, the answer of *moonlighting* is correct for this specific case. But people with similar questions in the future might be helped by the term *freelancing*.

Comment: @smci Actually, in this context it would mean that he has a main job as well. But I agree that the word on its own would lose the "he also has a main job" meaning.

Comment: Freelancing would be contradictory since it implies the person has no employer.

Comment: @Jool I have an employer at my day job, and then I go home and do freelancing work.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes this secret second job goes beyond mere work hours.

It is not unusual for people working with expensive (but moveable) equipment to be approached by other employees to work for them.

For example, the maintenance crew that cleans and waxes floors may be asked by another employee to do the same at the employee's home (or other business), using the company equipment and supplies.
This covert use of the company equipment is "conversion," I think, but not "theft."

One of my friends asked a worker in a window repair shop to come to her home and replace some of her windows (but he refused.) She was interested in hiring his expertise -- not in having him steal glass.

One of my friends is a nurse, and she was hired from the hospital she works at to give (on a private basis) short-term care to a sick person in his home.

Another friend of mine approached the guardian of an elderly person she was working for as a Home Health Aid and suggested that they hire her separately from the company she worked for, saving them money and giving her some benefit or other (which I forget right now.)

Floor cleaners, window washers, repair experts, painters ... workers like that are the people frequently solicited because of their expertise or for  the use of company equipment or supplies.

Most often this kind of moonlighting is paid for in cash, and the IRS has no knowledge of it. It's one of the main contributors, so I understand, to the "underground economy."

Answer (score -1):

IMHO, *moonlighting* doesn't necessarily imply not telling the primary employer (even if authorities think so). Perhaps that is because the Millennial generation does so much more part-time and gig work.

Also available in some contexts is *double-dipping*, although this is used more for persons collecting (often legally) a pension from one job—perhaps military, law enforcement, or fire-fighting as these tend to have remarkably young retirement ages—while working a second. I also saw it for a professor who, secretly, taught Monday-Wednesday at one university, then hopped an airplane to teach Thursday-Friday at another. He was dismissed from both. And that isn't so far from moonlighting except split by day instead of hour.

Comment: An example of double-dipping is when someone takes a retirement pension from the military and then, instead of going into actual retirement, they take a job as a police officer and collect both a police salary and their military retirement. This is sometimes frowned upon because pensions are intended to support persons in retirement, not provide extra income to working people. In some cases this is legal to do.

Comment: *moonlighting* does imply not telling your primary employer. otherwise it would just be *working two jobs*.

Comment: The term "moonlighting" does have a secretive connotation to it, even though it doesn't strictly mean that. Something that's secretive doesn't necessarily mean the activity is improper either.  But double-dipping definitely implies that the activity is illicit -- either getting paid twice for the same gig, or getting paid for something you did on someone else's time. When people refer to a legitimate activity as double-dipping, they do so jokingly, as in "I can't believe they're letting me do this" kind of way.

Comment: There is legal double-dipping, e.g. getting a military pension and working a job, and there is illegal double-dipping - charging two employers for the same time.

Comment: @MikeP it might be illegal, but it's incredibly common.